# in_array not working with associative array php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying very simply to use `in_array()` to check a key is in an array and then echo it's value.

```
$array = array("abc" => "123", 
               "def" => "456", 
               "ghi" => "789");

if(in_array("abc", $array))
    echo $allowed["abc"];
```

It should echo 123 but instead I get:

```
in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given
```

You can use associative arrays with `in_array()`?

I've also tried `array_key_exists()` but it gives the same error?

**Stupid error is stupid**

`$array` should be `$this->array` ... long day, delete me maybe?

Comment: The error suggests that `$array` is not what you believe it is.

Comment: `in_array` tests the value, not the key.

Comment: Your code shouldn't echo 123, nor complaint about $array being null. Whatever your actual code is, you're misusing [in_array()](http://php.net/in_array).

Comment: If you do a `var_dump` of `$array` just before the `if()`, it doesn't give anything right? If so (and I assume you've removed code between `$array` and `if()`), perhaps `$array` is being `unset`?

Comment: `$allowed` != `$array` ?

Comment: Stupid error, `$array` = `$this->array;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/array_key_exists) instead.

Comment: "I've also tried array_key_exists() but it gives the same error?" - from the OP

Comment: Oh, right - nevermind then :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
if (isset($array["abc"]))
```

Comment: @BillWoodger If it's only a typographical/minor mistake in the answer's code - why not edit that?

Comment: I did not think about the reviewers there and thought you meant that in general. You're probably right here

Answer (score 0):

in_array checks for whether the value exists in the array. To check whether a key exists, you should use isset.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$array = array("abc" => "123", 
               "def" => "456", 
               "ghi" => "789");


    if (isset($array["abc"]))
        echo $array["abc"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing $allowed and trying to echo out the value of $allowed('abc'), which doesn't exist.

Replace with $allowed with $array:

```
$array = array("abc" => "123", 
               "def" => "456", 
               "ghi" => "789");

if(array_key_exists("abc", $array))
{
    echo 'Found! '. $array["abc"]; // Update this line to $array
}
```

Alternatively, you can do an [array_flip()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php), then you can use in_array:

```
if( in_array("abc", array_flip($array) ))
{
    echo 'Found! '. $array["abc"];
}
```